# Overriding a control's name for screen reader purposes

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a WPF `DataGrid` control that is binding to a collection of objects. Everything is rendering on-screen as it should be.

`ToString()` has been overridden due to requirements elsewhere in the application.

The issue is that, when read by a screen reader (such as Microsoft's built-in Narrator), or when inspected via a tool like AccChecker / Inspect, the control's `name` is the overridden `ToString` value.

I want to be able to specify a descriptive name for the screen reader, but I can't find a method of doing so. I've tried setting `AutomationProperties.Name`, `AutomationProperties.ItemType`, and so forth, but none of the properties in `AutomationProperties` seem to have the desired effect.

Optimally, I'd be able to do this for both the data item itself, and also for the individual members of the columns.

Here's a complete demo of the issue I'm experiencing:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutomationProperties.Name="Test">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*" AutomationProperties.Name="Test2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the code:

```
public class FooItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(Id.ToString(), " : ", Name);
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public readonly List<FooItem> fooList = new List<FooItem>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        fooList.Add(new FooItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 1" });
        fooList.Add(new FooItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 2" });
        fooList.Add(new FooItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 3" });

        InitializeComponent();
        dgTest.DataContext = fooList;
    }
}
```

And just for completeness, here's a screenshot of Inspector.
[full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK3IM.png)
[image: Inspector screenshot]

Comment: can you apply a `DataGrid.RowStyle` which binds the `DataGridRow`'s `Name` property to a value in your `FooItem` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution... I had to use a style on `DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle` and `DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle` to set `AutomationProperties.Name`.

Ex:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutomationProperties.Name="Test"> 
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style>
              <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Row Item" />
         </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*" AutomationProperties.Name="Test2"> 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
        </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*"> 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
        </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```